# Does Samba ignore ACLs and umask?

Tags: samba, acl, umask

I have an ACL on /media/drv:
`sudo setfacl -dRm u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x /media/drv`

Likewise I set the special directory group id bit on /media/drv like this:
`sudo chmod g+s /media/drv`

When I make a directory or file from the Linux command line in /media/drv like this:
`# mkdir dir3`
`# touch file3`

I get these dir and file permissions:
`drwxrwsr-x+  2 user1 user1       4096 Apr 27 22:01 dir3`
`-rw-r--r--   1 user1 user1          2 Apr 27 22:01 file3`

However when I make a file or directory from a Samba share after much researching I finally realised that I needed settings like these in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to get the same permissions and keep things consistent and it didn't have anything to do with the ACL in place or umask setting.

```
#======================= Global Parameters =======================

[global]
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
logging = file
max log size = 1000
pam password change = Yes
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
server role = standalone server
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
unix password sync = Yes
idmap config * : backend = tdb

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[myShare]
path = /media/drv
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
force user = user1
valid users = user1,root
map archive = no
directory mask = 775
create mask = 664
```

**My Question:**
Samba has a setting `inherit acls` but does Samba ignore ACLs and the umask setting in Linux by default?

Cheers,

Flex

Comment: Why not just skip the step and `chmod 775 /media/drv` and then `chmod g+s /media/drv`? That does the same thing and you don't have to worry about ACLs. The only reason to put ACLs into place is if you want different groups and/or different users to have different permissions which would require them to be more granular.

Comment: If you want Samba to have the same effect as `chmod g+s` on a directory, generally you'd want `force group = user1`, not `force user`. However in your specific case you have `valid users = user1,root` so `force user` can be a good choice for you.

Comment: Thank you! I want `anyone` able to create and update files in /media/drv from `both` the linux command line `and` from a Samba share such that directories and files are maintained with consistent permissions... `drwxrwxr-x` for directories and `-rw-rw-r--` for files. @NasirRiley if I take your approach then the root user could create a file from the command line with permissions: `-rw-r--r--` as his umask is 022. Group ownership on that file is `user1` but permissions on that group would only be `r--` so only the `root` user can write to the file. Am I wrong about that? That's why I use ACLs.

Comment: The root user can do whatever that person wants. There isn't anything that you can do to stop that person. You can do only make it more difficult. Anyone with sudoer rights should have an understanding of how permissions work and shouldn't do that anyway unless they are going to set the permissions correctly.